Can i use an identifier outside of a namespace if i use a using namespace declaration in C++?
Im learning about namespaces but i have two doubts about it
In this code:
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){
    cout << "Please enter an int number " << endl;
    int n1 = 0;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "The number is: " << n1;
    return 0;
}

For example, if i have another name/identifier/entity named 'cout' defined in another namespace (with different functionality), lets say in the 'cblue' namespace, i still can use this 'cout' if i just type 'cblue::cout ... ' wherever i need to use it? or now i can only use the 'std cout'?
And the same, in this code:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Please enter an int number " << endl;
    int n1 = 0;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "The number is: " << n1;
    return 0;
}

I can still use the 'cblue cout' if i use 'cblue::cout ... ' or now i can only use 'std cout'?
Thanks in advance!!!

Some notes : using namespace std; is NOT recommended (to avoid nameclashes with other libraries).   Just learn to prepend ALL standard library types with std:: (the C++ committee chose a short namespace name for a reason). Also watch C++ Weekly - Ep 305 - Stop Using using namespace which might help you learn a bit more about namespaces too

Did you try actually using these and see if these compile? Using directive vs using declaration

You can always use cblue::cout to refer to the cout inside the cblue namespace, as long as it is declared previously.
When the compiler sees the name cout, it performs a process called name lookup. If the name is preceded by the scope resolution operator (::), it is a qualified name lookup, otherwise, it is an unqualified name lookup.
using std::cout; is a using-declaration, and using namespace std; is a using-directive. The first one introduces the name cout to the current scope and make it visible to the following unqualified lookups. The second one makes all the names from std namespace visible in the closest enclosing namespace (in your case, the global namespace) in the following unqualified lookups. In any case, they only affect unqualified lookups. Qualified lookups using cblue::cout are not affected. Note that cblue in cblue::cout is a name that would be handled by unqualified lookup and if there is any ambiguity in resolving cblue itself, cblue::cout could still fail.

Ok!, so in the last part, if i just have namespace named 'cblue, the 'cblue::cout' could not fail, but there could be problems if i have more than one namespace named 'cblue', right?

@CblueX That's right, although the other "cblue" found by the lookup does not have to be a namespace. As long as there is "something else" called "cblue" found by the name lookup, cblue::cout would fail.

The first example is bringing in only std::cout into the using namespace (in this case, global scope). In the second example, you are bringing in the entire std namespace.
In both cases, referring to cout without qualifying it will refer only to std::cout. To use cblue::cout, you have to qualify it.
You would have a problem only if you also have a using statement to bring in cblue::cout into the same namespace that brings in std::cout. Then they would conflict.
